# Is it valid in php to compare the value

Tags: php

`$newOrders` is an array and contains order objects...
`order_id` is an objects variable. I want to compare the `order_id` value to another `variable($orderId)` in `If` loop...
but it fails

Here is my code:

```
if($newOrders[$i]->order_id == $orderId){   
    echo "voila, found it:".$newOrders[$i]."<br>";
    return $newOrders[$i];
}
```

Comment: Tried checking whether the order_id has any extra spaces? Tried echoing the values ?

Comment: why not use in_array()?

Comment: What is the error? Have you implemented `____toString()` method in `Order` class?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I come across a piece of code that does not work - especially comparisons - I print out both sides of the variables (and often break down more complex variables, like your array) and actually look at the information, rather than assume I know from looking at the code.

It is inevitably a problem that is obvious as to what is wrong when the data is dumped out or otherwise manually examined. Tools such as Symfony [VarDumper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html) or just [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), or an IDE with breakpoints and variable inspection are all suitable to see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure this array contains object, have you checked? If yes, then how ?
2. What is the variable `$i` there, could you please put full code (I believe snippet should be in some loop `for` or `foreach`)
3. You can always check for a valid object of a class by

   ```
   if ($newOrders[$i] instanceof Order) {  //Presuming Order is your class name

   //do your stuff

   }
   ```
4. You can also check by using `var_dump()` function to check the variables inside the object.

I hope it'll help.